# Retriving the value of decoded JSON

Tags: php, json

I have problem with accessing an object (`stdClass`) after `json_decode`.

I don't know why there is problem with `-` as part of th key. Here is my code:

```
$a = array('body'=>array('short-description'=>'its short description','detailed-description'=>'its detail descriptionb'),'title'=>'its a title');
$b = json_encode($a);
$c = json_decode($b);
var_dump($c->body->short-description);
```

The problem is I can't get the value of short-description because the key have `-`.

Comment: It's just invalid syntax. You can't have variable names with a `-` either. `$foo-bar = 42;` is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
var_dump($c->body->{"short-description"});
```

You need to enclose it in braces.

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
$c = json_decode($b, true);

echo $c['body']['short']['short-description'];
```

The `True` Boolean converts it to a multi-dimensional array, and allows you to access the json that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap in brackets, such as:

```
var_dump($c->body->{'short-description'});
```